# Rename a file to an id

Tags: php

I'm making a website. I'm making it so when you upload a new profile pic, it will rename it to the user id. how do I do that? Its for profile pics. Its so i can have the user images and uploads to work better than they did. the code:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
require_once('auth.php');
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$temp = explode($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . $id.".".$temp)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE users SET picture='uploads/$id' WHERE mem_id='$id'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you already are with `$target_file . $id.".".$temp`. What's not working?

Comment: say i upload a file called doggo.png, it renames it to doggo.png4array

Comment: Because `$temp` is array!

Comment: Then figure out why `$temp` is an array and fix that.

Comment: but thern it would still be doggo.png4

Comment: Sure, because you haven't removed the file extension from `$target_file`. Understand your code. Print out its variables (using `print_r` or `var_dump`) and make sure they are what you expect. This is absolute basic PHP debugging stuff.

Comment: can i have some examples to help or it being sorted

Comment: i ment sonmeone to sort my code out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way your using explode is not right :

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

and then the file extension will be `end($temp)` :

```
$newfilename = $id . '.' . end($temp); // e.g. "png"

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $id.".".$newfilename)
```